How to register a SOAP web reference in .NET 8?
I am struggling with trying to register an older SOAP reference in a NET 8 Web API. I added the service reference WCF Reference now I am trying to use it and having some issues.
The trouble I am having is trying register it so I can inject it into a manager class for later unit testing. I see both a CustomerSoap interface and a CustomerSoapClient. I have added to this manager class the CustomerSoap interface as follows:
public class CustomerManager(CustomerSoap customerSoap)
{
 private readonly CustomerSoap _customerSoap = customerSoap;
}

This does not seem right as it is the interface but then I am not sure how to register this in the program.cs as well to use the asmx method the correct way.


I am not sure how to register this in the program.cs as well to use the asmx method the correct way.

In Program.cs, register CustomerSoapClient as the implementation of the CustomerSoap interface for use in the dependency injection container.
builder.Services.AddScoped<CustomerSoap>(sp =>
{
    var endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress("http://example.com/your-service.asmx");
    var binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
    return new CustomerSoapClient(binding, endpointAddress);
});

In your management class, inject the CustomerSoap interface:
public class CustomerManager
{
    private readonly CustomerSoap _customerSoap;

    public CustomerManager(CustomerSoap customerSoap)
    {
        _customerSoap = customerSoap;
    }

    // Use _customerSoap to call the service methods.
}

